# TypeError: navigation.navigate is not a function

Tags: typescript, react-native, react-navigation-stack, tsx

```
import React from 'react';
import {Button, View, Text} from 'react-native';

const RegistrationScreen = (navigation: any) => {
  return (
    <View>
      <Text>My Registration Page</Text>
      <Button
        title="Go Back"
        onPress={() => navigation.navigate('HomeScreen')}></Button>
    </View>
  );
};

export default RegistrationScreen;
```

I am getting the error, when i use .tsx as extenstion of the file. ex: - **RegistrationScreen.tsx**, and then got the error
//
***TypeError: navigation.navigate is not a function. (In 'navigation.navigate('HomeScreen')', 'navigation.navigate' is undefined)*** //

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`navigation: any` says that the variable navigation can be anything.  It can be a number, an object, undefined, etc.

```
navigation.navigate('HomeScreen')
```

Then you try to access a property `navigate` on your variable `navigation` and furthermore you are assuming that this property is a function which takes a string argument.

Typescript should tell you “hold up, I don’t know that I can do this!”

You should be able to import a type definition for navigation from the react-navigation package.  If not, this is sufficient for this particular usage:

```
interface Navigation {
     navigate(destination: string): void;
}
```

But what you’re getting looks to be a runtime error because you meant for the arguments of your component to be a props object containing a prop “navigation”, but you’ve written it so that the whole props object is called “navigation”.  This is what @realard is talking about in their answer about object destructuring.

In plain JS it would be:

```
const RegistrationScreen = ({navigation}) =>
```

But for typescript, we need to declare that the navigation property must by of type Navigation.  Which you can do in either of these ways:

Declare the definition for the props object inline

```
const RegistrationScreen = ({navigation}: {navigation: Navigation}) =>
```

Declare a type or interface for the props

```
interface RegistrationProps {
     navigation: Navigation;
}

const RegistrationScreen = ({navigation}: RegistrationProps) =>
```

Comment: Thanks, this line helped.                                                                                        
              ({navigation}: {navigation: Navigation})

Comment: I wanted to know about interface which has Navigation, why to use that ?

Comment: You need your component to be aware that the `navigation` property is a react-navigation object.  It looks like the actual type of `navigation` depends on which navigator type you are using.  check out these examples: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/typescript/

Comment: yeah, got it. Thanks

Comment: can you tell me how to use navigation on web and mobile using React Navigation 5X ? Will it work if i implement in a shared folder.? Thnak YOu

Comment: I don't know what you're asking.  Just look at the docs.

Answer (score 1):

You will need Object destructuring for your function RegistrationScreen. You can access navigation from the props with that addition:

```
const RegistrationScreen = ({navigation: any}) => {}
```

Comment: You’re right about needing destructuring, but the “:any” can’t go inside the destructured props.  You would need to do ({navigation}: {navigation: any}).

Comment: @LindaPaiste , Thanks man, was looking for this one. It worked.. Thanks a lot.